# How to compare two base64 strings in Javascript and ignore some differences

Tags: javascript, string, base64, compare, cypress

I'm getting one base64 string from API response and other one I'm converted image (which is in test data file) to base64 using cypress readfile method.

When I'm using below command the assertion is failing because there is tracking number difference which will be always new with every call.

And I'm getting 2 different base64.

```
//This base64 is from API response
var base64FromAPI =
        res.body.completedShipments[0].completedPackages[0].documents[0].image;
//Image is picked from Test Data file and converts to base64
        cy.readFile(`cypress/e2e/Testdata/Canada Post 02StoreId.pdf`, "base64").should(
          "eq",
          base64FromAPI
        );
```

Because there is tracking number on the label(image) which will be generated from API response is always different.

Is there any other way to compare base64 strings and to ignore some % of difference while comparing in cypress or javascript.

Or is there any other way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you can't do this at the base64 level. The differences in a raw bitstream like base64 are totally meaningless. The differences can only become apparent through rendering that image. Actually, what you need to do is pretty complex! I'm assuming it's not possible or a good idea in your use case to change away from having the server add the text to the image, to for example, using DOM to overlay it instead.

If that's the case, the only thing you could do is utilise [visual regression testing](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/visual-testing). With this, you can set a threshold on which a % similarity is defined.

Since the base64 comes from the API. This would probably mean also having test code that injects an `img` tag with the base64 as the source, so you can allow the visual snapshot to take place.

This works at the level of image analysis rather than on the actual bitstream. Internally it will render and compare the images.

Another way I can think of, though this is quite complex and I wouldn't pursue it unless the above did not work is to:

- Use image manipulation libraries to load the base64 into an actual rendered image in memory.
- Try to cut away/crop the superimposed text using image manipulation libraries in order to reliably remove areas of difference.
- Base 64 that.
- Compare that to a known stable base64 of the "rest" of the image.